# Conditional Highlighting with AND() function

Tags: excel-formula

I want a column to highlight cells only if it's older than a week and not blank. After reading through similar questions (apologies if this has been covered), I came to the below formula, but the blanks still get highlighted.

```
=AND(C5<=TODAY()-7,NOT(ISBLANK(C5)))
```

The date portion of the conditional works, but not the blank. I feel like I must be missing something very simple.

Thanks!!

Comment: You say you want a column to highlight cells that meet the criteria but then reference `C5` in your formula. In what range is your data on the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that the cells are really blank? The `ISBLANK` formula is `FALSE` also if there is an empty text string, non-printing characters, etc. present in the cell.

Try with `ISNUMBER` instead (which will also be `TRUE` if it is a date) (I assume here that your cells only contain dates or blank cells):

`=AND(C5<=TODAY()-7,ISNUMBER(C5))`

Answer (score 0):

`IsBlank()` will not return `True` if the cell is blank due to a formula. You can simply just use two double-quotes and it should work for you.

```
=AND(C5<=TODAY()-7,C5<>"")
```

Comment: But this will not work if the apparently blank cell contains a space or other non-visible characters.

Comment: OP just needs to provide more information. In most cases the cell appears blank due to a formula being in it.

Comment: Very true when one started with a clean worksheet, but if data is imported, you can get lots of "garbage" within apparently empty cells.